# Can we change SSL certificate dynamically in spring MVC controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ssl

My question is simple can we change ssl certificate dynamically?
Suppose i have two self signed certificates, /2/keystore.jks and /3/keystore.jks

My question is can i use first certificate for one url and second certificate for other one.

So far i have tried different code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class CertificateUtil {

    public static X509Certificate readCertificateFile(String keystorefilePath, String clientKeystorePassword, String alias)
        throws Exception {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystorefilePath),
            clientKeystorePassword.toCharArray());
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias,
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(clientKeystorePassword.toCharArray()));
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
        return cert;
    }

    public static void setCertificateInRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = readCertificateFile(required args...);

            request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate", javax.security.cert.X509Certificate.getInstance(x509Certificate.getEncoded()));
            request.setAttribute("java.servlet.request.X509Certificate", x509Certificate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried different solution nothing worked so far, if you can just point me in right direction that will be very good.

PS i used this command to generate certificate file

```
  keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias aliasweb -keystore keystore.jks -storepass aliasweb -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I after very long and time consuming RND i confirmed that it is not possible. SSL certificates are associated with IP address and this is simply not possible at least not yet.

Thanks.